# Gaiman's Hamnet

Tags: comics, neil-gaiman

[Hamnet Shakespeare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamnet_Shakespeare) appears as a character in Gaiman's *The Sandman*, in "A midsummer's night dream", and then in *The books of magic*, in "Book III: The Land of Summer's Twilight". In "Midsummer's", queen Titania takes a liking to the boy, and in "Summer's" we see that he has somehow ended up as one of her servants.

Is his story expanded in other comics (most likely not Gaiman's)?

I am not familiar with the follow-up series of "The books of magic", and couldn't locate any additional information one way or the other online. [**Edited to add:** To clarify, I am asking about the story of the fictional character, not about the real Hamnet.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hamnet doesn't have his story expanded on in other comics, whether Gaiman or otherwise authored.  For more information you might have to read some of the biographies of Shakespeare.

Comment: Heh, I meant to say "his fictional story". Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the actual play "Midsummer Night's Dream", Titania and Oberon are having a fight because Titania has kidnapped a human Indian child and replaced it with a changeling (this is the character that Hamnet is playing in Gaiman's story). It's implied that this is an accurate characterization of Titania in the world of the comics, and that she kidnaps (or coerces) him to the fairy world and fakes his death like she did with the Indian child in "Midsummer".